# VBA Array Faster Output to Excel Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is there a faster version method to output an array to excel?

I currently have data stored in 3 arrays `output_dt, output_s1, output_s2`.

Format sample:

```
15/12/2017  2165    2170
15/12/2017  2165    2175
15/12/2017  2165    2180
15/12/2017  2165    2185
15/12/2017  2165    2190
15/12/2017  2165    2195
15/12/2017  2165    2200
15/12/2017  2165    2205
15/12/2017  2165    2210
```

My current working solution is this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Strategies").Columns(4).ClearContents
Worksheets("Strategies").Columns(5).ClearContents
Worksheets("Strategies").Columns(6).ClearContents
[d1].Resize(UBound(output_dt)) = Application.Transpose(output_dt)
[e1].Resize(UBound(output_s1)) = Application.Transpose(output_s1)
[f1].Resize(UBound(output_s2)) = Application.Transpose(output_s2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However, this is painfully slow, even for just **150 rows**.

Any methods to speed this up?

Comment: Do you have calculation set to manual?  If not, maybe your worksheet is processing a lot of calculations after each of your `[d1].Resize(UBound(output_dt)) = Application.Transpose(output_dt)` statements.  Other than that, I can't understand why it would be slow at all.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't have the 3 columns in the same single 2D array? Do you have handlers running on `Worksheet.Change`? `Application.EnableEvents` is off? `[d1]` notation is implicitly referring to the active worksheet, is that intended? You're dereferencing the same worksheet 3 times explicitly and, assuming it's the active sheet, 3 times implicitly. Could be done only once. Gut feeling says it's the `ClearContents` calls that are taking forever; dumping a variant array with millions of rows is otherwise pretty much instant.

Comment: YowE3K - Appreciated, as when I turn off automatic calculations before and after, this solved it. I hadn't realised that it would re-calculate during each function. 
Mat's Mug - No - I just couldn't work out how to do it with my original source code (will add below if you can point me in the right direction). 
Is is slower then to reference the ActiveSheet rather than just specify which sheet I want 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

The loop I wrote for this to loop through the list of dates and 2 numbers to create a new set of data, creating 3x single 1D arrays.

```
    For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
        For j = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
            If data(i, 1) = data(j, 1) Then
                If data(i, 2) < data(j, 2) Then
                    x = x + 1
                    'MsgBox data(i, 2) & "-" & data(j, 2)
                    ReDim Preserve output_dt(0 To x + 1)
                    ReDim Preserve output_s1(0 To x + 1)
                    ReDim Preserve output_s2(0 To x + 1)
                    output_dt(x) = data(i, 1)
                    output_s1(x) = data(i, 2)
                    output_s2(x) = data(j, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```